# JavaFX retrieve TextView value outside Controller

Tags: java, javafx

**Edit:** For any future person reading this, you need to add `parameters` to the method I have shown in the post.
Instead of doing `+ textview +`, you do `+with parameter+` and then in the `controller`, you make `integers/strings` for the `parameters` and set them = to `textview.getText()`, then you put those `integers/strings` inside the `method parameters` of the method you are getting from the instance in the `controller` class.

**Original Post**
How do I get the value from a `TextView` in a method in another class outside the Controller class?
I cannot use `textview.getText();` outside the `Controller` class or it will just give me `NullPointerException`.

Here is my method from my other class:

```
    Controller c;
public void createRecipes() throws SQLException {
    openDB();
    if (connectionDB != null) {
        Statement st = this.connectionDB.createStatement();
        String insert = "INSERT INTO recipes "
                + " (ID, name, temperature, fan, redlight, bluelight, addwater) " + " VALUES "
                + " ( " + c.createID.getText() + ", " + c.createName.getText() + ", " +c. createTemperature.getText() + ", " + c.createFan.getText() + ", " + c.createRedLight.getText() + ", " + c.createBlueLight.getText() + ", " + c.createWaterLevel.getText() + " ) ;";

        st.executeUpdate(insert);
    } else {
        System.out.println("No connection established to the database.");
    }
    closeDB();
}
```

This is the textfield I am getting from my controller class:

```
c.createBlueLight.getText()
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the complete exception.

Comment: Please post relevant code inside the question as text. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: how do you initialize the controller? your question is rather how to access the controller.

Comment: I do not use any initializer, I just make an instance of my controller class as shown above, Controller c;

Comment: this is wrong! you need to get an instance of FXMLLoader (or give it one, but it's more like a user component).

Comment: can you please show an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use fx components outside of you controller! You should always separate logic and ui. So just pass the text content to the method.

Comment: Even if the code contains SQL ? I am using JDBC and using INSERT statements inside the method, shouldnt that be inside an SQL class?

Comment: Yes thats perfectly fine to use another class for that you should indeed do that! But when you call your method you just pass the content like this: method(textview.getText());

Comment: but the problem is I need to use the TextView values to insert the data, so they need to be in the same method. I have posted my method.

Comment: But you are calling the method from the controller right? Than why not change the parameters of your method to pass the text content? Instead of using c.createID.getText() just use a passed parameter!

Comment: This actually works! I just needed some parameters, thanks! You are a hero!

Answer (score -1):

This is an example of the right way to access controllers that are generated by parsing FXML files from `FXMLLoader`

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private TextField textField;

    public TextField getTextField() {
        return textField;
    }

    public String getTextFieldValue() {
        return textField.getText();
    }

}

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Controller controller = loader.getController();

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

So the controller is initialized correctly (the `textField` field is not null) and we can use it without problem, for example

```
TextField textField = controller.getTextField();
```

or

```
String value = controller.getTextFieldValue();
```

Comment: Don't expose UI components outside of the controller. Also, what is the purpose of the first line in your last code block?

Comment: I answer the question of the OP and it is how to use a controller that is automatically generated.
whether it will use UI elements outside the controller or will use something else (the two examples illustrate this) is not my problem.

Comment: That does not work, it will still return Null. The right way to do it is with parameters as "Aaron Stein 1" stated above.

Comment: you will get null if you did not make the fxml file correctly or the controller (if different types or names / id are different).